# gatsby ssr - add script to header before other plugins

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and need to head a script in the header BEFORE other plugin.

If I add it via `gatsby-ssr.js`

```
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => setHeadComponents([#MY-SCRIPT#]);
```

it's being added last.

How can I add it BEFORE other plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2022 update

Since the release of the [`Script` Gatsby component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/) (powered by Partytown) it's much easier adding third-party scripts. Just:

```
import React from "react"
import { Script } from "gatsby"

function YourPage() {
  return <Script src="https://my-example-script" />
}

export default YourPage
```

---

Why you use `gatsby-ssr.js` file if you can use `<Helmet>` tag, maybe it fits you. You just need to use it like this in any component:

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage= () => (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Index page" />
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://whatever.com" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script src="https://whatever2.com" type="text/javascript"/>
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

The snippet above will load your scripts inside `<head>` tag on the same order you've placed it.

If you need some kind of ordering and async approach, you can use `gatsby-ssr`, across `onRenderBody` and `onPreRenderHTML`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `onRenderBody`, use `onPreRenderHTML` to reorder your scripts.

```js
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) =>
  setHeadComponents([
    <script key='myscript' src='...' />
  ]);

exports.onPreRenderHTML = ({ getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }) => {
  const headComponents = getHeadComponents()

  // reorder your array with the sort method, by putting your item at top
  const orderedComponents = headComponents.sort((item) => (item.key === 'your-key' ? -1 : 1));  const orderedComponents = reorder(headComponents)
  replaceHeadComponents(orderedComponents)
}
```

For more info, [see the Gatsby docs on SSR API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#onPreRenderHTML).

Comment: I used the first answer, but this is definitely handful if I use a different plugins and must control the order..